# php running exec command in differennt directory than current

Tags: php, linux, shell, exec

I have two block of codes running on a shared host. I got both codes from posts here. First one worked but the second didn't. I am trying to get the 2nd block work as I don't want to use chdir to change my current working directory. I have tried many different combinations but none of them worked.

```
<?php

chdir('/user/bin/ghostscript');

$a = '/home1/user/public_html/a.pdf';
$b = '/home1/user/public_html/b.pdf';

exec('gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=2 -sOutputFile='.$b.' '.$a);

?>
```

This didn't work:

```
<?php

$a = '/home1/user/public_html/a.pdf';
$b = '/home1/user/public_html/b.pdf';

exec('cd /user/bin/ghostscript && ./gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=2 -sOutputFile='.$b.' '.$a);

?>
```

Comment: Instead of `./gs`, why not `/user/bin/ghostscript/gs`?

Comment: tried, didn't work

Comment: There might be other files that are required by ghostscript. add a soft link of '/user/bin/ghostscript' to your current directory.

Comment: somehow it started working without me doing any thing. now i can run it within the current directory without calling chdir. still wondering why tho. it might be the previous alls to chdir triggered the host to initiate ghostscript.